# In Bootstrap is there a way to have an html table with a cut down number of cells / rows but more for desktop browsers?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Is there a way in bootstrap's css to show some level of details for some devices and more for others.

My example would be groupon. If you visit groupon on your iphone you can see single column with offer after offer , yet visit the site on your desktop and you see different looking versions of the same offers, but they are positioned in a 4x1 box rather than a 1x1 scrollable list.

The whole page looks different. This must mean some elements detect they are being rendered on a small device and therefore dont show, am I on the right lines?

I am very new to bootstrap!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the bootstrap hidden-sm field on certain td elements to make them disappear on certain screen sizes.
It would also be worth look at the responsive tables class to make a scrollable div to fit wider tables as well